# choosing one to one result by a similarity matrix

Tags: python, algorithm, sequence-alignment

I build a function, that finds some alignment by some metric.

It gets a matrix with already computed similarity values:
`weighted_res` may be:

```
[[0.2, 0.5, 0.3],
 [0.1, 0.2, 0.4],
 [0.8, 0.2, 0.4],
 [0.1, 0.2, 0.7],
 [0.1, 0.2, 0.4],
```

My function maximizes the sum of the values for all combinations the indices of exs1 and exs2, but no index can be taken twice. The results are these optimal indices. The sum for (0,1), (2,0), (3,2), accordingly 0.5+0.8+0.7 produces the maximal score.

There are many cases, where finding for each column/row the maximum isn't enough. Let the matrix be:

```
[[0.1, 0.0, 0.1]
 [0.5, 0.6, 0.4],
 [0.5, 0.8, 0.3],
 [0.0, 0.0, 0.2]]
```

Here, it chooses (1,1), (2,1), (3,2), because 0.5+0.8+0.2 is the maximal reachable score.

My code is like the following and I fear, it is maximally ineffective. I would be happy about some hint to find a more efficient algorithm, than to compute all the possibilities and sum up and maximize. Here is that code:

```py
def one_to_one(weighted_res, exs1, exs2, mask):

    inner_cube_len = min(len(list(exs1)), len(list(exs2)))
    turned = False

    if (len(exs1) < len(exs2)):
        exs1, exs2 = exs2, exs1
        weighted_res = weighted_res.T
        mask = mask.T
        turned = True

    x_to_choose = np.array(list(itertools.permutations(range(len(exs1)), inner_cube_len)))
    y_to_choose  = np.array(list(range (len(exs2))))

    weighted_res_overall = \
        weighted_res[x_to_choose,y_to_choose].sum(axis=1)

    best_overall_row  = np.argmax(weighted_res_overall)
    best_x_values     = np.array (x_to_choose[best_overall_row] )

    valid_mask        = mask[best_x_values,y_to_choose]
    best_res1         = best_x_values[valid_mask]
    best_res2         = y_to_choose[valid_mask]

    if not valid_mask.any():
        return [],[]
    if turned:
        left_value   = best_res2.tolist()
        right_values = [[x] for x in best_res1.tolist()]
        exs1, exs2 = exs2, exs1
        weighted_res = weighted_res.T
        mask = mask.T
    else:
        right_values =  [[x] for x in best_res2.tolist()]
        left_value   =  best_res1.tolist()
    return left_value, right_values
```

With input values with lengths of 8 and 6 of the input results, the `weighted_res_overall` has a size of 20160 and that grows extremly fast.

Comment: What is the expected output? `Then it chooses the indices (0,1), (2,0), (3,2)` who chooses?

Comment: Can you explain what the function does? If you expect that we deduce from the code you probably won't get any answers

Comment: My function maximizes the sum of the values for all combinations the indices of `exs1` and `exs2`, but no index can be taken twice. The results are these optimal indices. The sum for `(0,1), (2,0), (3,2)`, accordingly `0.5+0.8+0.7` produces the maximal score. I edited that that in my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found it, it's named Hungarian Algorithm, but with maximizing instead of minimizing the score. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hungarian_algorithm

There is a scipy implementation of it: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.18.1/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.linear_sum_assignment.html

Or https://github.com/src-d/lapjv

Thanks for thinking about it!

Answer (score 0):

If you transpose the matrix then you can easily find the maximum value for each column without repeats as follows:

```
from numpy import array

mat = [[0.2, 0.5, 0.3],
       [0.1, 0.2, 0.4],
       [0.8, 0.2, 0.4],
       [0.1, 0.2, 0.7],
       [0.1, 0.2, 0.4]]

mat = array(mat).T

maxis = [max(col) for col in mat]
```

If you then want the sum instead of a list of the maximum values, you can change the final generator expression to:

```
max_sum = sum(max(col) for col in mat)
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Sorry, that it doesn't help, see my edits with the additional example.